# New ids by month

Tags: sql, date, count

I'm thinking a lot about this but I cannot find an answer, and I'm not very good at SQL queries.

Table1:

```
id    |     month
_________________
123   |   11/2015
124   |   11/2015
123   |   12/2015
124   |   12/2015
125   |   12/2015
```

I need a query that gives me amount of new id's per month.
in the example, I would like to output:

```
#id  |     month
_________________
 2   |   11/2015
 1   |   12/2015
```

Because "123" and "124" are in 11/2015, so 2
Because "125" is not in 12/2015, so 1

Sorry if I'm being unclear, I tried look it up using self joins and lags and I cant find the answer

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to filter out `id`s that already appeared in a previous month, and then aggregate:

```
select count(*) id_cnt, t.month
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id 
    and t1.month < t.month
)
group by t.month
```

Comment: might also need a distinct somewhere in there if an id can repeat multiple times in a month, but this is something OP must decide if he needs